# What are the vertex and fractal shader instruction count limits in WebGL for Chrome?

Tags: glsl, webgl, hlsl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

How many instructions can a vertex and fractal shader each have in WebGL in Chrome, without taking rendering time per frame into account?

from: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angleproject/5Z3EiyqfbQY

> So the only way to know an instruction count limit has been exceeded
> is to compile it?
>
> Unfortunately yes.   Note that you should probably try to compile and
> link it to really be sure since some systems may not actually do much
> at the compilation phase.

Someone must have some rough samples or a limiting factor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific limit. It's up to the driver. A high end GPU will have a larger limit than a low end mobile GPU. There's also no way to know how many instructions a particular line of GLSL will translate into since that's also up to the particular GLSL compiler in that particular driver.

Answer (score 1):

This is an aspect that is not mandated by the Khronos specification, and hence varies depending on the GPU, or the shader compiler if ANGLE is used.